# python SimpleHTTPServer reverse proxy

Tags: python, simplehttpserver

Currently for development purpose we are using pythons **SimpleHTTPServer** to expose a folder which has static content like html,css and js.

Within our js files we will be calling couchDB url, but the couchDB url is in different machine or ip address.

Is there a way so that when we hit http://localhost:8000/couchDB/user python can proxy pass to http://couchdb-ipaddress:5894/user ? I am new to Python. Currently I cant use any other tool. I found this link but didn't understand what it is.
http://effbot.org/librarybook/simplehttpserver.htm

if its not possible in python's **SimpleHTTPServer** then i will use **Apache http server** and config the **httpd.conf** file.

Comment: I believe this is not possible..

Comment: It’s perfectly *possible* (SimpleHTTPServer is a full-fledged server), but largely a waste of effort.